# How to deploy .net web service in ftp?

Tags: .net, web-services, ftp

I need to deploy my .NET web service on live server so that I can access it in my live site.

I only have the ftp credentials with me. Please tell me how can I deploy my web service and thereby access it in my live site.

Comment: You really cant do much with just FTP. What other access and more importantly infrastructure do you have on that server?

Comment: Can't you simply use the Publish command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use batch file(s) to do it.
Here is some info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic8.aspx